# Syntax error at input 'end of line without line continuation' error

Tags: pine-script, indicator

```
ma(source, length, type) =>
    type == "SMA" ? ta.sma(source, length) :
    type == "EMA" ? ta.ema(source, length) :
na
```

I keep getting
Error at 14:45 Syntax error at input 'end of line without line continuation'

i checked the tabs and spaces nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

```
ma = switch ma_type
    "SMA" => ta.sma(source, length)
    "EMA" => ta.ema(source, length)
    => na
```

where ma_type for example

```
ma_type = input.string('EMA', '', ['SMA','EMA'])
```